# Why does terraform ask me to recreate subnets on every apply to a GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am very familiar with Terraform against AWS.  Trying to port a project over to using GCP now.

I have a fairly simple .tf file:

```
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc" {
  name                    = "${local.resource_prefix}-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "public_subnet_1" {
  name          =  "${local.resource_prefix}-public-subnet-1"
  ip_cidr_range = local.subnet_public_1_cidr
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc.id
  region        = local.gcp_region

  private_ip_google_access = false
}
```

This creates fine on the first `apply`, but on every subsequent `apply`, it asks me to force replace the subnet:

```
  # google_compute_subnetwork.private_subnet_1 must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "private_subnet_1" {
      ~ creation_timestamp       = "2020-06-11T08:12:27.002-07:00" -> (known after apply)
      + enable_flow_logs         = (known after apply)
      + fingerprint              = (known after apply)
      ~ gateway_address          = "10.1.100.1" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                       = "projects/(project-id)/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/foo-private-subnet-1" -> (known after apply)
        ip_cidr_range            = "10.1.100.0/24"
        name                     = "foo-private-subnet-1"
      ~ network                  = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/(project-name)/global/networks/foo-vpc" -> "projects/(project-id)/global/networks/foo-vpc" # forces replacement
        private_ip_google_access = false
      ~ project                  = "(project-id)" -> (known after apply)
        region                   = "us-east1"
      ~ secondary_ip_range       = [] -> (known after apply)
      ~ self_link                = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/(project-name)/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/foo-private-subnet-1" -> (known after apply)
    }
```

The `network` of the subnet appears to be what's forcing the replacement, but this is coming from the VPC attributes, and as best I can tell I'm following every online example I can find.

What am I missing?  Why the mismatch between name and id in the network, or is it something else?

Comment: Did you create the subnetwork with Terraform initially and still see that diff? Or did you create it outside of Terraform and then import it?

Comment: Nothing done outside of Terraform other than obtaining credentials and upping quotas.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is simply to replace:

```
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc.id
```

with

```
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc.self_link
```

`self_link` is a bit of an odd name for this, and not what I've seen in a couple of tutorials so far, but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Also seems odd that Terraform let me create it in the first place with `id`

Comment: This is [a quirk of the Google Cloud provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/guides/getting_started.html#linking-gcp-resources) specifically. Seems to be a result of the underlying API having three different identifiers for many objects: an isolated name (`name`), a path relative to the API root (`id`), and an absolute API URL (`self_link`). The underlying API seems to accept both the relative and absolute URLs, but it always _returns_ the absolute one.

Comment: That's a good explanation.  Feel free to submit it as an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove .tfstate file and .tfstate.backup file after each apply